# Interfacing multiple ethernet sensors on ROS system (single ethernet port)

Tags: ros, lidar

My system consists of the following: A PC with a single ethernet port and other USB ports, a robot mobile base, a SICK LMS lidar with ethernet cable, a Velodyne sensor with Ethernet cable.

The robot is connected via serial to usb converter and works fine. The lidar can also be connected to the ethernet and works fine. Now that we have acquired a velodyne 3d Lidar, I am confused as to how to connect this to the computer as there is only one ethernet port available. Should I use a router? Has anyone tried to connect multiple sensors like this. I would be thankful if you can provide details.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Alex, but I'm afraid that questions which can only be answered by the pre-sales or technical support team for a specific manufacturer or supplier aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. *[Practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* are always welcome here though, so if you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: As a guess though, if all three ethernet devices have different IP addresses and are on the same subnet, then all you need is an Ethernet hub or switch (a router is not necessary, but it's Ethernet ports will usually work in the same way as a hub for the local network segment). If your PC and your SICK LMS are communicationg by [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) however, then you will need to reconfigure your network (either with static IP addresses or DHCP) to get all three to communicatio via a hub or switch.